# How eslint requires that variables must be explicitly typed

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I hope that each variable must have an explicit type when declared.

How should I configure eslint?

```js
const a = 10; // Error: Variable a does not explicitly specify a type

const b:number = 10; // Right!
```

Comment: That's not really necessary, as TypeScript will already infer the type of `10` to be `number`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following inside your .eslintrc.json:

```
...
"@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": 0,
"@typescript-eslint/typedef": [
    "warn",
    {
        "variableDeclaration": true
    }
]
...
```

From the docs on [no-inferrable-types](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-inferrable-types/)

> TypeScript is able to infer the types of parameters, properties, and variables from their default or initial values. There is no need to use an explicit : type annotation on one of those constructs initialized to a boolean, number, or string. Doing so adds unnecessary verbosity to code -making it harder to read- and in some cases can prevent TypeScript from inferring a more specific literal type (e.g. 10) instead of the more general primitive type (e.g. number)

Hence you need to turn off the rule for **no-inferrable-types** first before setting the **typedef** rule to achieve your goal.

Read more about the [typedef](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef) rule

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a rule for this.

There is a rule on the other hand for the exact inverse. Enforce to not use type declaration for infered types [no-inferable-type](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-inferrable-types.md).

You can see a list with all the rules [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules).